# Failed to upload AppName.app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to run my app on my iPad and I get the following error:

Failed to upload AppName.app

However when I run it in Simulator there are no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay your $99 to Apple, log into the developer portal, provision your device (can also be done through organizer). Install that provisioning profile on your iPad and then try and build & run again in xcode.

I highly recommend the organizer route, it simplifies all this for you. But if you opt to do it through the web, there are instructions in the portal to tell you what to do.